# Android Studio fail generate signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, signing

I'm installed Android Studio 3.5 and started to use it with my old project (gradle 2.14 and I want save this version). 
Build in debug and release mode work fine. But when I try generate signed APK an error message are appeared:

"The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)"

How it can be? Why I can't just asign APK?

[image: gradle-wrapper.properties]

Comment: did you update your gradle version in your project-level build.gradle file? If you did, please post that file also.

Answer (score 1):

I'm downgrade to Android Studio 3.4.1 and signing worked fine.

Comment: sadly this seems to be the only option for me too

Answer (score 0):

Please make a change in the last line as  follows:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

and try to Rebuild your project again.

Answer (score 0):

In your project inside gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Change this line..

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

In your project level build.gradle..

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()   // or mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'  // change to this version     
    }
}
```